# Why does my iPad camera use JPG instead of HEIF?

Tags: ipad, photos, camera, ipados, heif

**Environment**

- iPad 6
- iPadOS 13.3

**Setting**

- `Settings` app -> `Camera` -> `Formats` -> `High Efficiency` (instead of `Most Compatible`)

[image]

**Result**

Although the formats setting says

> To reduce file size, capture photos and videos in the high efficiency HEIF/HEVC format. Most Compatible will always use JPEG/H.264.

, all the photos are saved in JPG. This is confirmed by the steps below.

1. Connect my iPad to my desktop PC whose OS is Arch Linux (not Windows nor macOS).
2. Open the `iPad/DCIM/100Apple` directory.
3. Only `*.JPG` files are found.

Is this a bug? How can I use HEIF?

Comment: *"all the photos are saved in JPG."* how are you checking that? I guess it's exported as such, not saved.

Comment: @ankii I first connected iPad to my PC whose OS is Arch Linux (not Windows nor macOS). Then I opened the `iPad/DCIM/100APPLE` directory to find only `*.JPG` files.

Comment: Which iPad model from https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/index-ipad-specs.html do you mean by "iPad 6"?

Comment: @nohillside iPad 9.7" 6th Gen (Wi-Fi Only). According to the [official support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207022), this model supports HEIF. (Actually, iPhoneSE is not supported and my iPhone SE does **not** show the setting in the first place.)

Comment: You use the standard Camera app and don't post-process the photos, I assume. Did you try to change to JPG, restart the iPad and enable HEIC again?

Comment: @nohillside Yes. I use the pre-installed default Camera app and no post-process is done. I've already tried toggling the setting and rebooting but nothing changed.